# AS3 Download Animation

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button, download

I want to try to do a specific thing.

I've an input field, the user will fill this input and after he will start the animation by clicking on a button (the added text will rotate).

Is it possible to make a button that allows the user to download an animation .swf only with the text he add before and without the start button and the input field layers ?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to generate an swf but it is very (**very!**) difficult if you don't know what you are doing. Your best bet would be to let him download it as video file. You can use native extensions to generate all kind of video formats (assuming you are working with Air, of course), if not, you can use the FLV writers that are available online (e.g. http://www.zeropointnine.com/blog/simpleflvwriteras-as3-class-to-create-flvs/ ).

Comment: Oh okay, thank you ! Then with this class, it's possible to generate a video with only the layers i want ?